# What does "Obtaining a CVE" mean

Tags: cve, mitre

I've have seen the term around and I mostly get that it is referred to when someone reports a vulnerability to Mitre.

But what does this mean practically? Are you listed somewhere as the reporter? Is this something people use on their CVs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When someone discovers a vulnerability, they can request a Common Vulnerabilities  and Exposures (CVE) id. This id will be linked to the vulnerability and is linked to you as a person.

Whether it is used on a resume is totally up to you, I personally started doing this recently in order to show my activities.

Comment: "*When someone discovers a vulnerability, they can request*" Actually, anyone can request a CVE ID. It is often the finder but not always.